# Cannot send through rocketmail smtp from CFMAIL

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to send an e-mail through rocketmail using the ColdFusion CFMAIL tag..  I have this same account set up in Thunderbird, so there are no issues with the rocketmail account.

```
<cftry>
    <cfmail 
          from="#fromemailaddress#" 
          to="#toemailaddress#" 
          failto="failto@email.com" 
          server="plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
          username="#fromemailaddress#" 
          password="#password#" 
          subject="Test E-mail" 
          usessl="yes" 
          usetls="no" 
          port="465">
          This is a test e-mail.
     </cfmail>
     <cfcatch type="any">
          <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
      </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

I am getting no errors.  I cannot check the mail logs because this is on shared hosting site, although I called their customer support and they said no errors are being found in the e-mail logs.  I am just not getting any e-mails. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you try on your local development CF server?

Comment: It works fine with the built-in server and it works fine when I try to send via the gmail smtp server.  I need to be able to send through the smtp server of a user's e-mail account, which in this case is rocketmail.

Comment: Are you sure the user's password is correct, and is the user subscribed to Yahoo Plus?

Comment: Yes.  It wouldn't work in Thunderbird otherwise.

Comment: I believe I have found the issue.  As Raymond suggested, but it didn't dawn on me why until this morning, I tried this on my local dev server, then checked the mail log.  Eureka!  I got the error: SMTPSendFailedException: 553 From address not verified.  Will see what has to be done and update shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I added a replyto to the cfmail tag, and it worked, although not quite as expected.

The SMTP server settings for Rocketmail are plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com, use SSL, Port 465.

I wrapped my cfmail in three nested cfloops, one for the usessl attribute, one for the usetls attribute, and one for the port attribute.

I got e-mails from the following:

```
 SSL=yes, TLS=no, Port 465
 SSL=yes, TLS=yes, Port 465
 SSL=no, TLS=yes, Port 25
```

I also do not get an e-mail in my rocketmail inbox or sent box, which is what I was ultimately hoping for (unlike gmail, which I do).  I will just have to add myself to the TO attribute, but really shouldn't have to.